# Retain values during myform_validate()

Tags: entities, 6

In Drupal 6, I have a custom form validation function, where:

- I copy the value from field A to field B, if field B is empty.
- I call `form_set_error()` when the field B contains more than X characters.

Validation works fine, and the error is set. The problem is that the value in field B is not retained when the form is rebuilt: field B remains empty. I want to keep the value in field B after validation (when the error is set) to make it easy for users to edit it down to the right length.

My validation function looks like this:

```
function myform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state['values']['field_b']['0']['value'])) {
        $form_state['values']['field_b']['0']['value'] = $form_state['values']['field_a']['0']['value']; 
      }
      if (strlen($form_state['values']['field_b']['0']['value']) > 260) {
        form_set_error('field_b', 'Text in field b is too long');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to retain the value in field B when the form is rebuilt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set a form value from within your validation callback you'll need to use something like [form_set_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_value/6). Values that are assigned directly in the manner shown above will not be retained, but that function should do the trick! It's specifically intended for this purpose - setting a form value during the validation phase.

For example:

```
function myform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state['values']['field_b'])) {
        // Note that the $form array - not $form_state - is used in the first parameter.
        // The second parameter is the value you are setting.
        // Third just pass the $form_state array itself, which will be altered by form_set_vaue().
        form_set_value($form['field_b'], $form_state['values']['field_a'], $form_state); 
      }
      if (strlen($form_state['values']['field_b']) > 260) {
        form_set_error('field_b', 'Text in field b is too long');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `form_set_value()` is what I was looking for. I'm struggling to find the right value to replace, as it's part of a (CCK fieldset) array.

I understand I have to pass in an '#parents' array, but can't seem to find the correct key/array path.

The field itself is a textfield that's part of a fieldset, so I've tried mulitple variations of `array('#parents' => array('fieldset', 'field', '0', 'value')`. Anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Answering my own question: `form_set_value(array('#parents' => array('field_a', '0', 'value')), $form_state['values']['field_b'][0]['value'], $form_state);` seems the right way to get to the field's value.